# Using R, how to collapse into a single row the sum of different rows in a dataframe that belong to the same year but have different values

Tags: dataframe

I have a three column data frame named "salmon" containing data on 22 species of Pacific salmon population from the 1930s to 2022. For each species, I want to group the data by year and add up the values of the "NUMBER_OF_SPAWNERS" column that correspond to the same year, and show the result as a single row per year. Some years, not all, have data collected from multiple sources. How can I achieve this?

This is my code to load the data.

```
salmon <- fread("data/SPS_2022.csv", select = c('SPECIES', 'YEAR', 'NUMBER_OF_SPAWNERS'))
head(salmon)
```

SPECIES        YEAR   NUMBER_OF_SPAWNERS
                 
LCchinook2020   2012       1096
LCchinook2020   2013        946

I factored the "SPECIES" column and arranged it by year:

```
salmon2 <- salmon %>% mutate(across(SPECIES, as.factor)) %>% group_by(SPECIES) %>% arrange(YEAR, .by_group = TRUE)
```

How can I modify this code to add up the "NUMBER_OF_SPAWNERS" values that correspond to the same year for each species, and show the result as a single row per year?

The end product will be a time series plot for each species.